# Как сделать update в php используя pdo для mssql под linux?

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, update

Есть кусок кода:

```
<code lang="php">
   $dsn = "dblib:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
    $db = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

    $sql="update dbo.X\$USERS set XU\$FLAG=XU\$FLAG | 8 where xu\$loginname='$username'";
    $sth=$db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute();
</code>
```

выполняется, но `update` не отрабатывает, поле остается неизменным.

Изгуглил весь инет, пробовал и `bindvalue` и `exec(array())`, `update` все равно не отрабатывает.

Вопрос: подскажите, как?

P.S: `select` работает отлично.

Comment: вы уверены, что сформированный текст sql запроса вообще выполняется в sql-server?

Comment: забыл добавить что в sql mangement studio запрос выполняется, а знак $ из php приходится экранировать

Comment: дак и что execute возращает то? true или false? ошибки PDO что говорят? если все ок, то убедитесь в корректности условия where.

Comment: зы: в своем первом комментарии под "сформированным текстом" я имел в виду вывести значение переменной `$sql` скопировать ее в SQL MS и выполнить

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, заработало:

```
$dsn = "dblib:host=$host;dbname=$dbname";
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);

$val='blinstvo';
$tmt = $dbh->prepare( "INSERT INTO pbx.dbo.tmp (name) VALUES( '$val' )");

$dbh->beginTransaction();
$tmt->execute();
$dbh->commit();
```